# Trigger a build when there is a new tag on a specific branch

Tags: git, jenkins, tags

I can trigger a build on all tag creations by setting `refspec` to

```
+refs/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*
```

but in my case I only want it to build when a tag is added on a specific branch. Setting the `branch specifier` to the branch name, for example `master`, does not seem to work (no build was triggered). Is this possible to configure Jenkins to trigger a build on tag creations on a specific branch?

Comment: Hi @Derek. Are you using some type of jenkins plugin? webhook or pulling approach?

Comment: @JRichardsz I'm using the Github hook trigger which will get notified whenever something changes in the Github project.

Comment: and in your jenkins?? Some plugins get total access to github payload (https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/3ded3cb429d51cc826373e8bded15a8f) in order to make complex rules like your requirement. Other question : Are you using pipeline job or simple jobs in jenkins?

Comment: @JRichardsz Simple jobs instead of a pipeline script. Not sure how much data it is getting from the webhook. That's not something that I can modify.

Comment: are you using a plugin in your jenkins or how jenkins is triggered when github detect tag creation event ? All depends of this.